# Use Groupby and Sum to reduce a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with some recurring values in one column. I want to group by that column and sum the other columns. The dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Edit: here is the code to create the dataframe. Notice the column called 'Able' which is the index.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Able': ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'Orange'], 'Baker':[ 'New York', 'New Jersey', 'New York', 'New Jersey'], 'Charlie':[3,4,'',7], 'Delta':['',5,6,''],'Echo':[100,200,300,400]}).set_index('Able')
```

The result should group on 'Baker' and sum the other three columns. I've tried various flavors of groupby and pivot_table. They return the correct two rows (New York and New Jersey) but they only return 'Baker' and the sum for the rightmost column, 'Echo.' The far left column 'Able' which is the index for the source dataframe should be ignored. My output should look like this (edited thanks to @corralien for spotting an error):

```
Baker   Charlie Delta   Echo
New Jersey  11  5   600
New York    3   6   400
```

How do I return all the columns, ideally without listing them by name in the code?

Comment: It would be super helpful if you provided the code to construct the sample dataframe for a quick copy/paste.

Comment: Can you check your output, please? Delta values are probably swapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the space with 0 and agg sum. This will depend on what dype, the  last three columns are. I repoduced df for you, feel free to edit if I got the dtypes wrong and edit the question. The forum will guide you.

Dataframe

```
   df=pd.DataFrame({'Baker':[ 'New York', 'New Jersey', 'New York', 'New Jersey'], 'Charlie':[3,4,'',7], 'Delta':['',5,6,''],'Echo':[100,200,300,400]})
```

Code

```
 df.replace('',0).groupby('Baker').agg('sum')
```

Output

```
            Charlie  Delta  Echo
Baker                           
New Jersey       11      5   600
New York          3      6   400
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='Baker', values=['Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo'], 
                   aggfunc='sum').reset_index()

        Baker  Charlie  Delta  Echo
0  New Jersey     11.0    5.0   600
1    New York      3.0    6.0   400
```

Ensure your columns C, D, E are numeric, try `df.replace('', 0)` or `df.fillna(0)` to fill your blank cells.